# Convergence of a series 1/(2n+1)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm looking for a way to get an estimate on a sum of the following series:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2i-1}$$

My exact question would be the solution for $n=500$ but I'd be interested in the generic solution as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2i-1}=\frac{H_{n-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}+\log (2)$$ Now, expanding the harmonic number, for large values of $n$, the following approximation can be made $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2i-1}=\left(\frac{1}{2} \log (n)+\frac{\gamma }{2}+\log
   (2)\right)+\frac{1}{48 n^2}-\frac{7}{1920
   n^4}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^5\right)$$ Limited to the first term this gives, for $n=500$, an approximate value of $4.08905914555514$ while the exact value is $4.08905914555508\cdots$

Comment: I'm sorry but: What? What do you call $H_{n-1/2}$? The only thing that I've seen called $H_n$ is $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$, which obviously doesn't make any sense for a fractional index. Not to mention that $H_n$ is rational, the LHS is rational, but $\log(2)$ is irrational.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Compare the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$ with the integrals $\int_1^{n} \frac1x \text{d}x$ and $\int_1^{n+1} \frac1x \text{d}x$.

**Edit:** The question has been changed from $\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} \frac{1}{i}$ to $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2i-1}$. Could you think of a similar trick here?

Comment: Sorry I realised that I messed up the formula, the operands need to step by two.

Comment: I guess if I sum $1/i$ from 1 to 1000 then subtract the sum of $1/i$ from 1 to 500 divided by two that gives the same result. I'll try solving that

Answer (score 3):

If
$s_n
=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2i-1}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
s_n
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2i-1}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{2i-1}+\frac{1}{2i}-\frac{1}{2i}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{2i-1}+\frac{1}{2i}\right)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2i}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{i}-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}\\
&=H_{2n}-\frac12 H_n\\
\end{array}
$,

where
$H_n
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}
\approx \ln n +\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2}+...
$,
so

$\begin{array}\\
s_n
&\approx (\ln (2n) +\gamma+\frac1{4n}-\frac1{48n^2}+...)
-\frac12(\ln n +\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2}+...)\\
&\approx (\ln n  +\ln 2 +\gamma+\frac1{4n}-\frac1{48n^2}+...)
-\frac12(\ln n +\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2}+...)\\
&\approx \frac12\ln n +\ln 2 +\frac12\gamma+\frac1{48n^2}+...\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Get the exact answer on Wolfram-Alpha by entering [the description of the summation required as shown](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%201%2F%282*x-1%29%20for%20x%20from%201%20to%20500)